# Add custom errors to angularjs validation directive and display all errors in a popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an angularjs directive that does validation, this is the code:

```
app.directive('modelValidation', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        var modelFieldName = attr.ngModel;
        var model = scope.validationModel;
        var valid;

        // scope.validationModel is being loaded async so we need to watch when the promise is resolved.
        scope.$watch('validationModel', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal) { model = scope.validationModel; }
        }, true);

        //For model -> DOM validation
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
            valid = true;
            if (model != undefined) {
                if (modelFieldName in model) {
                    var errorMessage = checkFieldValidation(model, modelFieldName, value);
                    if (errorMessage.length > 0) {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                } 
            } 

            ctrl.$setValidity('modelValidation', valid);
            return valid ? value : undefined;
        });
    }
};
});
```

The field `scope.validationModel` holds a json object returned from the server and inside this json I have the validation data such as the regEx that I need to test and the error message to be displayed if the validation fails.
The `checkFieldValidation` returns the desired error message if the validation fails, else it returns an empty string.
I want to use this directive for all of my form elements, and I want to display all of the returned errors inside a popup.

The validation itself works, but I can't seem to find how to use those error messages as I desire.

I don't know if using angular's directive is the best solution for my case, I am open to another solutions that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [ng-messages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) directive.
This way beneath every input you can display the correct error message. You can check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/OMvrjy)

For the dialog, you can use form.$error to get all the errors and their correct error message.

You can see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/keithra/pen/QmQJQd) to see how it all works. If you want to set messages in $error, just set them on your controller using the error name like :

```
 $scope.userForm.name.error_required = "This is required !"
 $scope.userForm.username.error_minlength = "This is too short !"
 $scope.userForm.username.error_maxlength = "This is too long !"
 $scope.userForm.email.error_email = "This is not an email.."
```

then use a Object.keys() function in html like *(note that you have to link it in your scope elsewise it won't be defined in your html file, hence my getKeys function)* :

```
{{userForm.email['error_' + getKeys(userForm.email.$error)]}}
```

Comment: Can you give me a simple explanation on how to inject errors into form.$error within the directive? and also how to use it...

Comment: There you go, two different codepens, first one for ng messages, second one to save messages using $error and also for you to understand pristines, valid, etc... Hope it'll help you out.